# pick random photo from iphone library

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an iOS app and at a certain point I would like to let the user touch a button and it would select and show a random image from his iphone library.

At first I was loading all the photos in a array and was selecting objectAtIndex:aRandomNumber.
Everything worked fine on the simulator as I only have a few images recorded in the library, but as soon as I tried this on my iPhone I realized how naive I was. The app simply stop after being blocked a moment, it's easy to understand that it's impossible to use this approach with  the memory of an iPhone.

Does anyone know of a way that would let me know the number of pictures in the library (for the modulo in random) and then a way to pick one at an index, without first loading it in an NSArray?

... should I forget this feature ?

Comment: forget this feature is a very good idea as I doubt somebody would see it as feature.

Comment: So the reason you minus my question is the word feature ? In my app it is one, as at a certain point the user has to draw some things to make the under image appear, which could be a random photo from his library.

Comment: I did not minus your question, it was somebody else, but this shows that my comment was not only my thinking and your question confirms this as well, I thought. A user would think that you either show a picture of your choice that comes with your app or that he selects himself a picture of his choice. Imagine he has some fotos he does not want to show to somebody. Maybe even Apple has a restriction about that and would refuse your app (but I did not check)

Comment: Well, I can understand this point of view, I didn't think of it that way. But the way I do this, the user can either pick from camera, from library or pick random. It shows his choice and let him change before doing anything else, so unless he clicks random in front of his friends, it wouldn't happen.

Comment: Anyway, the way things goes, it seems I won't find any answer and will have to remove the random button, not that it would be any real problem either... :-)

Comment: If the user grants your app permission to access the photo library, there is nothing wrong with your app displaying a random photo from the library.

Comment: If the person down voted you because they thought a random picture was a bad idea, then they are not using the downvote for what its meant. Also IMHO, your app should be the features you feel are useful for the user, not what is easy for you to do.

Comment: This may assist you with your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Comment: @logixologist Of course, I can't disagree with you, but the way things were turning I took the easy way out. Furthermore, this app will never be really distributed, it's my final project for school (and my first ios app). Anyway, thank you for pointing me to this question, I'll be able to look more deeply into it.